# Question about this sentence , -られる and なくちゃ

Tags: grammar

Is this "being able to" or "passive" られる　here?

> 僕も楽しみに待っていられるようなものが何かなくちゃ…

I think the part that i struggle the most with, is

> 楽しみに待っていられる

Don't they have the same meaning? "looking forward to"?

I understand so far : "I, also, to be able to look forward i have to have something to do to look forward" ??

with "何かなくちゃ" meaning : " to have something i have to do"?

But i'm afraid i'm making a mistake here, is he trying to say that he "Need something to look forward to" ? but by "doing something"?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Idunno「楽しみに待つ」は切らないで考えてみたら・・

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「僕{ぼく}も楽{たの}しみに待{ま}っていられるようなものが何{なに}かなくちゃ…」

In this context, 「待っていられる」 is the potential form of 「待っている」, so it means "***to be able to wait***".

It is **not** the passive voice form here even though that form is also 「待っていられる」.

> with "何かなくちゃ" meaning : " to have something i have to do"?

Nope.  I think you are thinking of 「何か**し**なくちゃ」.

「何かなくちゃ…」 in this sentence means along the lines:

「何かなくちゃ**おもしろくない**」、「何かなくちゃ**つまらない**」, etc.

In other words, a word or two (that essentially mean "***no good***") are left unsaid at the end.  ***The ellipsis is the hint***.

Thus, the sentence would mean:

> "It would be no fun/no good/boring if I didn't have something I could be looking forward to."

↓

> "I've got to have something I can be looking forward to doing/having, etc."

Comment: @Idunnowhattocallmyself If you have additional questions about the same sentence, please feel free to [ask them separately](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  You can link to this question when you do.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think seeing in the dictionnary that both "楽しみ" and "待つ" had the meaning of "  to look forward to; looking forward to" threw me off !